# Is the OData $search operation supported on Office 365 mail API?

Tags: odata, office365

I need to perform a fulltext search in an Office 365 mailbox, preferably using the new REST (OData) API.

While not documented, I had my hopes up that the OData Search operation would be supported:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/Folders('Inbox')/Messages?$search=FooBar
```

And indeed it seems like the current version of the Office 365 api returns messages from my inbox with this query, but it doesn't really filter them on the search keyword.

Is this a feature we can expect to be released in the near future? It would greatly enhance the usability of this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search is something that we want to add, but it's not there yet. Keep an eye on our [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/) or follow me on Twitter ([@JasonJohMSFT](https://twitter.com/JasonJohMSFT/)) to get updates on new features in the API.

Comment: great to hear it's being considered. Thanks!

Comment: @Jason Johnston how about now, is the search supported?

Comment: Yep! https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Search

Comment: @Jason Johnston Looks like the search not supported for events. Any work around there for key word searching on events subject and body?